# Digesting value in YAML file into MD5 hash

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml, digest

I have a YAML file containing usernames and passwords.

Overview of YAML:

> ```
> users:
>  test:
>     password: test
>   test2:
>     password: test2
> ```

I want to encrypt the password value into an MD5 hash using `Digest::MD5` for example:

```
user:
  Lost Bam:
    password: testtesttest #<=I want to overwrite this password with a MD5 hash
```

In Digest is there a way to encrypt a hash value? If so how do I implement this into a YAML file?

md5.rb Source:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'digest'

private

    def load_file
        File.exist?('info.yml') ? YAML.load_file('info.yml') : {users: {}}
    end

    def read_file
        File.read('info.yml')
    end

    def save_file( hash )
        File.open('info.yml', 'w') { |f| f.write(hash.to_yaml)}
    end

    def add_user
        hash = load_file
        hash["users"][prompt('Enter username:')] =
            { "password" =>  prompt('Enter password:') }
        puts "Encrypt information?"
        information = gets.chomp
        case input
        when /yes/i
#           hash = Digest::MD5.digest(["password"]'value')<-Doesn't work
#
#This is where I want to be able to encrypt the 
#value of the password key that was entered by the user
#
#           save_file( hash )
        else
            puts "Add another?"#Not completed yet
        end
        save_file( hash )
    end
```

main.rb Source:

```
require_relative 'md5.rb'

def main
     puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, '')
                >
                >To load information type "L" to quit system type "Q"
                >
            END
    input = gets.chomp.upcase
    case input
    when "L"
        add_user
    when "Q"
        exit_system
    else
        exit_lock
    end
end

def exit_system
    puts "Exiting..."
    exit
end

def exit_lock
    puts "Locked out, please contact system administrator"
    exit
end

def restart
    puts "Encrypt more?"
    input = gets.chomp
    if input =~ /yes/i
        return true
    else 
        exit_system
    end
end

def prompt( message )
    puts message
    gets.chomp
end
main
```

Comment: Do you mean digest the values after reading from the YAML file?

Comment: @Edward yes I do, I edited the question

Comment: What do you mean "certain things" and why is it difficult to implement in YAML? Please provide some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do, or that shows where you've searched and why the answers didn't help you write code. As is it's not clear what you've done. Please read "[ask]".

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry about that, I added the source codes of both of my files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Digest::MD5:

```
require 'digest'
Digest::MD5.digest('value')
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html

Comment: That will digest the value of the password key..?

Comment: if you pass in the password, it will return a encrypted hash